# Uploading form-data without files via apache FileUpload

Tags: java, file-upload, multipartform-data, apache-commons-fileupload

I'm using Apache Commons FileUpload to upload data to my server - some text-fields and one file-item. Sometimes there is only text-fields without files and i need to proceed this requests too. When i try to do it, `org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Stream ended unexpectedly` occurs on the line `List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request)`. 
There is my code:

```
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
    import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

      private boolean isMultipart;
      private int maxFileSize = 50*1024*1024;
      private int maxMemSize = 40*1024;

      protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
          ...
        try {
          ...
          isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
          if(!isMultipart){
            return;
          }
          DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(maxMemSize,
                  new File(properties.getProperty("temp")));
          ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
          upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
          UploadRequest uploadRequest = new UploadRequest();
          try {
            List fileItems;
            // NEXT LINE EXCEPTION
            fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()){
              FileItem item = (FileItem)i.next();
              if(!item.isFormField()){
                String fileName = item.getName();
              }
              else {
                ...
              }
            }
...
```

If i send to it files and textfields - i can read all fields. If i don't send files - i can't also read textfields because of exception. Any solutions to load only text without files with `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646189/why-did-i-get-fileuploadexception-stream-ended-unexpectedly-with-apache-commo

Comment: No. I knew why this exception occurs in my case. I just need way to avoid this exception and continue to proceed data.