# files uploading via server ip but not from domain name

Tags: java, apache, file-upload

I have got a problem while uploading files on my server, when i am trying to upload files using Internet Protocol of my server. It is working fine but when i am trying to upload same files from my domain name. It is not working.

my application is deployed on Apache tomcat 7.0 on Linux machine.

**Server.xml**

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" 
           disableUploadTimeout="false"
           connectionTimeout="6000000"
           maxPostSize="0"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           />
```

**

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.parseRequest(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:145)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.processUpload(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:88)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.parse(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:80)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequestWrapper.<init>(MultiPartRequestWrapper.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.wrapRequest(Dispatcher.java:709)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.wrapRequest(PrepareOperations.java:131)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:983)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:887)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:94)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:362)
    ... 23 more

Mar 25, 2014 1:20:07 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger warn
WARNING: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
```

Comment: please share what error you were getting.

Comment: i am getting Stream ended unexpectedly exception, please have a look on stack trace..

Comment: it's perfectly working if i try to upload using server ip like 222.22.22.22:8080/myapp

Comment: what are your finding for this `Exception`?

Comment: i have goggled and found that server is closing the stream, i have changed my server.xml file but still problem.. you can check my server.xml configuration..

Comment: please check these question it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263809/apache-commons-file-upload-stream-ended-unexpectedly http://www.coderanch.com/t/359182/Servlets/java/FileUploadException http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646189/why-did-i-get-fileuploadexception-stream-ended-unexpectedly-with-apache-commo

Comment: i have already checked them but nothing solving my problem...

Comment: are you using multi-part?

Comment: yes i am using multi-part

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multi-part add `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp